# General formula for $\frac{a^{2n+1}-a^{2n-1}}{a^n-a^{n-1}}$. Is such proof correct?

Tags: proof-verification, self-learning

I have a very simple case: Find general formula for $\frac{a^{2n+1}-a^{2n-1}}{a^n-a^{n-1}}$.
Of course dividing one by another was quite simple with outcome: $a^n(a+1)$. However I would like to prove it. My question is: is this enough as a proof? If this was something really complicated, and I would prove it in such manner, would that be enough?

for $n=1$:

$$\frac{a^3-a}{a-1}=a^2+a=a(a+1)$$

for $n=2$:

$$\frac{a^5-a^3}{a^2-a}=a^3+a^2=a^2(a+1)$$

for $N=n+1$:

$$\frac{a^{2(n+1)+1}-a^{2(n+1)-1}}{a^{n+1}-a^{(n+1)-1}}=\frac{a^{2n+3}-a^{2n+1}}{a^{n+1}-a^n}=\frac{a^2(a^{2n+1}-a^{2n-1})}{a(a^n-a^{n-1})}=a\cdot a^n(a+1)=a^{n+1}(a+1)$$

Comment: Why do you think that division is not a proof? -- But also: Did you notice which values of $a$ are forbidden (for the statement as such, so both kinds of proof are affected)? -- And finally, your result and proof do not match the problem statement

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen What do you mean by "result and proof do not match the problem statement"?

Comment: Compare yor result with lab's answer

Comment: Oh,there was mistake. Sorry. There should be $2n$ in nomnator instead $n$.

Comment: @Misery. Use the same trick as lab did.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{a^{n+1}-a^{n-1}}{a^n-a^{n-1}}$$

$$=\frac{a^{n-1}(a^2-1)}{a^{n-1}(a-1)}$$

$$=a+1$$ assuming $a(a-1)\ne0$

Comment: $a\ne 0$ is only needed if $n\ne 1$